# Learning interfaces and hierarchies, where to place certain variables and methods?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract, class-hierarchy

So as part of a car rental system I need to write classes to represent large and small cars, the difference between these being that they have different size tanks and consume fuel at different rates. Currently my approach is to have an interface, Car, implemented by an abstract class AbstractCar, which is extended by two concrete classes SmallCar and LargeCar. However this is my first time using interfaces and abstract classes (we are just covering them in class and this assignment is designed to assess our knowledge of them) and I'm having trouble knowing what to place in what class.

The fill method implementations are exactly the same, they just need to refer to the correct value of FUEL_CAPACITY, so it feels that I should be implementing these methods in the AbstractCar class, but then I don't know how to get them to refer to the correct FUEL_CAPACITY values. The field fuelLevel is also obviously held by all cars so it feels that I should declare it in AbstractCar, but then I cannot access it from the subclasses without removing its privacy.

Would anyone be able to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding about interfaces and inheritance? One thing I've been considering is producing an enum CarType, having AbstractCar hold a CarType as a field and all implementation is done in the AbstractCar class using if statements to switch to the correct FUEL_CAPACITY value, and simply using SmallCar and LargeCar as constructors or factory classes without much or even any actual implementations.

Thanks in advance for any help I realise its a bit long winded, however I try to make sure I'm fully understanding the concepts we are learning and that I'm implementing them correctly rather than just botching together something that 'works' but might not necessarily be the correct or most elegant solution.

Comment: You can transfer the logic to the `AbstractCar` with the values. Then just set those values in the contrustor of `SmallCar` and `LargeCar`. This would be one approach. Like you pointed out, you always have to have the common logic in the parent class. You want to avoid duplicate code. Then you just have to make sure you set different values in the constructor. And if you know the fix value, you can even omit giving parameters to `SmallCar` or `LargeCar` and just set those fixed values in the `super()` call inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transfer the logic to the AbstractCar with the values like you pointed out. Then just set those values in the constructor of SmallCar and LargeCar. This would be one approach. Like you pointed out, you always have to have the common logic in the parent class. You want to avoid duplicate code. Then you just have to make sure you set different values in the constructor. And if you know the fix value (as you do from the given example), you can even omit giving parameters to SmallCar or LargeCar constructors and just set those fixed values in the super() call inside the constructor.

Here is the implementation of my solution.

The interface `Car`, where I REMOVED the `getFuelMethod()` method since the access level has to be protected:

```
public interface Car {

  RegistrationNumber getRegistration();

  int getFuelCapacity();

  // int getFuelLevel(); this can not be implemented
  // all methods in an interface are PUBLIC
  // so you have to lower the access level by removing it from the interface

  // HERE goes the rest of the method signatures

}
```

}

The abstract class `AbstractCar`:

```
public abstract class AbstractCar implements Car {
  // this is the common variable
  // that is why we save it in the parent class
  private int fuelCapacity;

  private int fuelLevel;

  // we forward the value to the parent constructor with the super call
  public AbstractCar(int fuelCapacity) {
    this.fuelCapacity = fuelCapacity;
    // I set the value to 0 for the start, but
    // you can also pass the value to the super call,
    // same as fuelCapacity - it is up to you
    this.fuelLevel = 0;
  }

  // The getters and setter allow us to retrieve the values
  // from the abstract class through capsulation!

  // here we have the getter to be able to retrieve the value from SmallCar and LargeCar
  public int getFuelCapacity() {
    return.fuelCapacity;
  }

  public void setFuelCapacity(int fuelCapacity) {
    this.fuelCapacity = fuelCapacity;
  }

  protected int getFuelLevel() {
    return fuelLevel;
  }

  protected void setFuelLevel(int fuelLevel) {
    this.fuelLevel = fuelLevel;
  }

  // HERE goes the rest of the code

}
```

Here is the `SmallCar` implementation:

```
public class SmallCar extends AbstractCar {

  private static final int FUEL_CAPACITY = 45;

  public SmallCar() {
    // we set the value in the parent class
    super(FUEL_CAPACITY);
  }

  public int drive() {
    // HERE goes the logic for drive for SmallCar. Same method is needed
    // in the LargeCar class, because the logic differes.
  }

  // HERE goes the rest of the code

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best answer given for my situation as the fuel capacity values are constant, 45 for small and 65 for large. Would it be better practice to declare both these constants in the interface as SMALL_FUEL_CAPACITY and LARGE_FUEL_CAPACITY or declare each one separately in the concrete classes?

Also, I realised that the implementations of drive() do differ slightly. So the drive method needs to be implemented in the concrete classes, but also needs to write to fuelLevel which is now in the abstract class. Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Thanks again!

Comment: Since fuel capacity is a constant, so I would recommend to declare it in the concrete class and pass the value in the `super` call in the constructor, as I suggested. Regarding the `drive` method, you are right. If the implementation differs, but you still have the same method signature, then it is recommended to declare an abstract method in the abstract class.

Comment: But I see now you already declared the method in the interface, which is an even better approach. So you are OBLIGATED to implement this function in the concrete class - AbstractCar can not be instantiated, which means it does not have to implement the `drive` method.

Comment: Regarding the `fuelLevel`, if you store this as a value, then put the declaration into the abstract class. If you calculate this every time you call `getFuelLevel`, then there is no need to declare a variable in the abstract class, you just implement the method on the concrete class. Hope I manage to explain it good enough. From your question it seems this value also represents a state, so I will update my solution and add the state to the abstract class.

Comment: Thanks for expanding. My problem is that the 'fill' method needs to change the 'fuelLevel' variable, which is fine now that both of those are declared in 'AbstractCar'. However, 'drive' needs to be implemented in the concrete classes, but also needs to change the 'fuelLevel' variable. Now that 'fuelLevel' is located in 'AbstractCar' and is private, I can no longer change it from the concrete classes, as I need to implement 'drive'. So I'm wondering what the correct workaround for this is? Seeing as Java has no access modifier to give access for subclasses only

Comment: You just use a getter and setter method in the abstract class. I will update what I mean in my code.

Comment: Done. Now you have the `fuelLevel` in the `abstract` class. And you have full access to that value with the setter and getter for `fuelLevel`. This is the way to go and uses the OOP principle CAPSULATION.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ideally I want the only classes to be able to use setFuelLevel to be the subclasses, is there any possible way to do this? Or should I just make it package-private?

Comment: You can make it package-private, yes. You do that by removing the int `getFuelLevel` method from the interface. Because all methods defined in the `interface` has to be PUBLIC. Seems like you fully understand all of it.

Comment: Sorry, just to share some light. If the classes are not in the same package, then you have to use the access level `protected`, otherwise you are allowed to use no modifier. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) you have the full explanation in case you do not know the access levels very well.

Comment: Hope I manage to help you out. If so, then we can close this question as answered, right?

Comment: Yes, this solution did work for me :) thank you. The classes all live in the same package so default access works fine here. The only problem I'm having now is that the interface itself doesn't seem absolutely necessary to me, but if I got rid of it, the entire project would have no interfaces, which seems strange because we were told we would need them (and I can't see where else one would be useful). We were told we should also be using late binding somewhere, but I can't seem to see where that would be used either. Do you have any ideas of where this functionality could be useful?

Comment: I would suggest to use the interface for the getters in the `abstract class`. That way you will gave the access to those values. And I would add the `public int drive()` method to the interface. The basic idea with interfaces is to have a skeleton of methods, but also to serve to hide the implementation. So that you can create an instance like this: `Car car = new SmallCar`. That way you have the access to all states of a car like fuel capacity, fuel level, registration, is rented, etc. That way you have even more control over the instance, and you hide the logic you do not want to show.

Answer (score 0):

If your Capacity is only one property (only data) of Car, use [@Jernej K approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799444/6209021), but if calculating the capacity may have some logic, use this:

Best way is to use **abstract methods**. you put a method to `abstract Integer getCapacity();` in your abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractCar implements Car {

    private final RegistrationNumber registration;
    private boolean isRented;

    AbstractCar() {
        this.registration = RegistrationNumber.getInstance();
    }

    public RegistrationNumber getRegistration() {
        return registration;
    }

    public boolean isRented() {
        return isRented;
    }

    //You can use this method in other methods of AbstractCar, but is implemented in your concrete classes
    public abstract Integer getCapacity();

    public boolean isFull() {
        if (fuelLevel == getCapacity()) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }


}
```

and then use it in other functions. and in your concrete class, you define the body of method:

```
public Integer getCapacity(){
    //Your logic to calculate capacity for every concrete class here
}
```

Comment: I think a better approach is to have the value set in `AbstractCar`, because they both need that value. We would you have two getters. And since abstract classes allows you to have implementations, there is no need to override the getter for each class.

Comment: You would use the overriding, if there would be different logic involved for SmallCar and LargeCar. But with his example, you only have one fix value. That is why I think your approach is over kill.

Comment: If the real case is same as the example, yes this approach is overkill, but i think real use cases is more complex and if he need logic to calculate or select capacity based on other data members of concrete class, this will be used.

Comment: Also  you can not force other implementer of abstract class to have a special capacity value or logic, you can't force theme with this constructor approach.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by forcing. I am just using the `super` call, which is one of the basics in programming and save the value in the abstract class. This is a valid and recommended approach. You use abstract classes to hide common logic for inheritance. That way you avoid saving each class state in their corresponding class since the value is a fixed value. Or if you do not like constructors, use the getter and setter from the abstract class, when you want to save common states.

Comment: Ok, if that's only a member without logic, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer and mentioned your approach, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yeah the fuel capacities are just two constants, 45 for small cars and 65 for large ones. So in this case Jernej K's approach would be more appropriate I think? thanks anyway though :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide `FUEL_CAPACITY` from the class user but not from the further developers, you can declare it as `protected` in the *AbstractCar* and initiallize it with a proper value in the child classes. Also I would declare a *getter method* `getCapacity()` in the *AbstractCar* which returns this value.